# Need a C# signature for AcquireCredentialsHandle win32 api function

Tags: c#, winapi, sspi

I have somehow come out with a signature for this api call, but the call does not work in the expected fashion. Some vital data structures are not get populated properly hence I am not getting intended output. The signature I've used is:

```
[DllImport("secur32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern ulong AcquireCredentialsHandle(
        string pszPrincipal,
        string pszPackage,
        ulong fCredentialsUse,
        IntPtr pvLogonID,
        ref SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY pAuthData, 
        //IntPtr pAuthData,
        IntPtr pGetKeyFn,
        IntPtr pGetArgumentKey,
        //ref SecHandle phCredential,
        IntPtr phCredential,
        ref TimeStamp ptsExpiry);
```

Please ignore the comments.

The c-based function call I used for reference can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374715(VS.85).aspx). I want to know what did I do wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried [this at pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/secur32/AcquireCredentialsHandle.html)?

Answer (score 2):

The struct above doesn't seem correct as the API[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380495(v=vs.85).aspx) the documentation states

```
typedef struct _SecHandle {
  ULONG_PTR       dwLower;
  ULONG_PTR       dwUpper;
} SecHandle, * PSecHandle;
```

That means that the code above will work on 32bit but should be

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_HANDLE
{
    public IntPtr LowPart;
    public IntPtr HighPart;
    public SECURITY_HANDLE(int dummy)
    {
        LowPart = HighPart = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
};
```

This will work on both 32bit and 64bit modes.

The rest will be the same as previously

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_INTEGER
{
    public uint LowPart;
    public int HighPart;
    public SECURITY_INTEGER(int dummy)
    {
        LowPart = 0;
        HighPart = 0;
    }
};

[DllImport("secur32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern int AcquireCredentialsHandle(
    string pszPrincipal, //SEC_CHAR*
    string pszPackage, //SEC_CHAR* //"Kerberos","NTLM","Negotiative"
    int fCredentialUse,
    IntPtr PAuthenticationID,//_LUID AuthenticationID,//pvLogonID,//PLUID
    IntPtr pAuthData,//PVOID
    int pGetKeyFn, //SEC_GET_KEY_FN
    IntPtr pvGetKeyArgument, //PVOID
    ref SECURITY_HANDLE phCredential, //SecHandle //PCtxtHandle ref
    ref SECURITY_INTEGER ptsExpiry); //PTimeStamp //TimeStamp ref
```

You should also be careful to free the handle as it is unmanaged.

Answer (score 1):

From [pInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/secur32/AcquireCredentialsHandle.html)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_INTEGER
{
    public uint LowPart;
    public int HighPart;
    public SECURITY_INTEGER(int dummy)
    {
    LowPart = 0;
    HighPart = 0;
    }
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_HANDLE
{
    public uint LowPart;
    public uint HighPart;
    public SECURITY_HANDLE(int dummy)
    {
    LowPart = HighPart = 0;
    }
};


[DllImport("secur32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  static extern int AcquireCredentialsHandle(
    string pszPrincipal, //SEC_CHAR*
    string pszPackage, //SEC_CHAR* //"Kerberos","NTLM","Negotiative"
    int fCredentialUse,
    IntPtr PAuthenticationID,//_LUID AuthenticationID,//pvLogonID, //PLUID
    IntPtr pAuthData,//PVOID
    int pGetKeyFn, //SEC_GET_KEY_FN
    IntPtr pvGetKeyArgument, //PVOID
    ref SECURITY_HANDLE phCredential, //SecHandle //PCtxtHandle ref
    ref SECURITY_INTEGER ptsExpiry); //PTimeStamp //TimeStamp ref
```